# detect the change of direction

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on a school project in high school.
Is there a way to get the types of manoeuvre (turn left or right.) in real time? Do you know if there is a function "turn left / turn right" in DirectionsRenderer?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no such function. I believe you'll have to do a manual implementation to achieve this.

I would suggest first to analyze the returned response by logging it. On the returned response, there's a **"maneuver"** property in which the value tells what action should be performed. Some of the values were: **"turn-right", "turn-left", "turn-slight-right"**, etc. These values will be a big help for your project.

Here's a sample response:

```
    {
      "distance" : {
         "text" : "0.3 mi",
         "value" : 403
      },
      "duration" : {
         "text" : "2 mins",
         "value" : 120
      },
      "end_location" : {
         "lat" : 41.8745324,
         "lng" : -87.6292009
      },
      "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eS Dearborn St\u003c/b\u003e",
      "maneuver" : "turn-right",
      "polyline" : {
         "points" : "oir~FdbzuOdAArDE|@CpBE`AAZ?tBAH?lA?"
      },
      "start_location" : {
         "lat" : 41.878156,
         "lng" : -87.6293093
      },
      "travel_mode" : "BICYCLING"
    },
```

Hope it could help and goodluck on your project!

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you mind accepting/upvoting my answer? thanks :)